# Interesting ad idea

Tags: discussion, advertising

I recently saw this ad on Reddit. I thought it would be a great ad to run on Stack Overflow as well.

[Reddit ad http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/782/reditadd.png](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/782/reditadd.png)

I feel it promotes good-natured advertising.

Comment: It also has the side effect of telling everyone who has never heard of "AdBlock" before that such a thing exists; maybe that user will be curious, google it, learn about it, like it, install it. I realize that many of the SO users will at least know what it is, but probably not all of them, and the % is much smaller on SU. Note that I'm not saying it's a bad idea; I'm just pointing out a possible drawback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a really poorly-targetted ad.

- Anyone who knows what AdBlock is (and will be able to see the humour), probably will never see the ad in the first place.
- People who do see the ad and choose to find out what AdBlock is, are mostly going to keep it installed; meaning the number of ad targets is only ever reduced over time.

Aside from my personal belief that ad revenue is destined to die off, this ad in particular just doesn't make any sense given the medium.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds to me like they are advertising adblock.